# Change behaviour of the modifier keys system-wide

Tags: xorg, xkb, key-mapping, xinput

I’d want to make modifier keys (control, alt, shift, meta, super, lv3_switch) to act like usual keys, I mean, without holding one of them to perform associated key combination. Say C-x M-1 can by typed like

```
press Ctrl key — release Ctrl key 
press x key — release x key 
press Meta key — release Meta key 
press 1 key — release 1 key
```

so that can be performed even with one hand key-by-key!

Comment: The term you are looking for is "sticky keys". A similar question has been asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/a/414535/71229): use `xbset sticky -twokey -latchlock`.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully thanks, but fix `xbset` to `xkbset`? Someone may not get it.

Comment: I just lazily copied the command from the superuser link! Now my previous comment is outside the edit window. It looks like the real command is: `xkbset sticky -twokey -latchlock`.